# WPF ListView ScrollBar visible to false

Tags: wpf, listview, scrollbar

Is it possible to force the horizontal (or vertical) scroll to NOT display even when needed?

The thing is that I need to display colors that are different depending of the item. That works fine but you can clearly see that the color does not reach both edge of the list view, which is kinda ugly. To make things worse, I have in my listview another listview that contains another list of item. Those item's background does not come even close to the edge of the listview.

Comment: The thing is that I need to display colors that are different depending of the item. That works fine but you can clearly see that the color does not reach both edge of the list view, which is kinda ugly. To make things worse, I have in my listview another listview that contains another list of item. Those item's background does not  come even close to the edge of the listview. 
If there is a way to do this, I am all in.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You can specify the visibility of the scrollbar for both vertical and horizontal scrolling to four options, using the `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` and `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility` attached properties: `Auto`, `Disabled`, `Hidden` and `Visible`.

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
```

`Disabled` will have it never show up and scrolling is not possible, `Hidden` will have it not show, but will allow users to scroll using text selection and arrow keys/mousewheel, etc.

Comment: Disabled is exactly what I neeeded. Thanks !

Answer (score 11):

Directly on the scroll bar:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" />
```

If you're doing it in a control that implements it in its ControlTemplate:

```
<StackPanel ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" />
```